# How to connect to Mongo using Extent 3.0.0

Tags: extentreports, extent

How to connect to Mongo using extent 3.0.0. I cannot find extent.x there.
My POM is using this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please note I have tried everything mentioned here: http://extentreports.com/docs/extentx/

Comment: Version 3 has different usage. You need to use the ExtentXReporter. See version 3 docs for it. http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/

Comment: Thanks .This is working fine now.